# ruby apply puts to array

Tags: ruby

For methods that the elements of an array responds to, I can do

```
[1,2,3].each(&:to_s)
```

But for:

```
[1,2,3].each {|i| puts i}
```

I cannot do:

```
[1,2,3].each(&:puts)
```

How do I elegantly apply `Kernel` methods such as `puts` to the objects in an array? Would there be a more Rubyish way?

Comment: Your last example seems pretty ruby-ish to me...

Comment: `puts [1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`puts` is a method, defined on `Kernel` to convert it to `proc`, use:

```
[1,2,3].each(&method(:puts))
```

[`Symbol#to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) has a specific meaning, basically sending itself to the receiver.

One might convert any method to `proc` to pass it to block:

```
%w[1 2 3].map(&method(:Integer))
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. Now, I just need to wait 10 minutes before SO allows me to flag this as "answer"

Comment: To expand on this a bit for other perusing parties the leading `&` in this case is to convert the argument to a block via the object's `to_proc` method. For instance `&:to_s` (as in the question is `Symbol#to_proc`) and `&method(:puts)` (as in the answer) is `Method#to_proc`. For `Symbol#to_proc` is sends the `Symbol` to the block argument where as `Method#to_proc` sends the block argument to the `Method`

Comment: This is neat and all but I think OPs last example is more idiomatic and, more importantly, _much easier to understand_ than these examples...

Answer (score 5):

Your last example is idiomatic Ruby:

```ruby
[1,2,3].each { |x| puts x }
```

There are certainly other ways to do the same thing but the code above is straightforward and easily understood by any Rubyist.

Comment: This will never pass my CR. Ruby was invented to be syntax sugared and it deserves the ability to have this syntax sugar usage.

Comment: @mudasobwa I suppose we have differing opinions here - to me, simplicity and clarity are more important than sugar.

Comment: Never is a strong word. IMO, very few things in programming should use the words never or always. I have to agree with @maerics on this one. Code is written, yes; but in the end, code is meant to be read. It's read by your future self and the next guy that has to maintain your code.

Comment: Using an explicit block where the shorthand might be used does not bring additional simplicity nor clarity. The same way as using _“get“_ instead of all other verbs does not make English text better readable. Ampersand notation is a core of ruby and if it decreases the ability of developers to read it smoothly, I would question developers’ expertise/skills in the first place. And yes, I ban `{ |e| e.to_s }` instead of `(&:to_s)` explicitly for the sake of readability and simplicity, not vice versa. It makes me think they do not understand the basics and I put some effort to make them do.